# docker swarm easy rolling update without downtime

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a service with just 1 instance on a docker swarm. It exposes a port to the machine.

I want docker swarm easily apply rolling update without downtime. Right now i am running `docker service rm` and then `docker service create`

Using just 1 instance / replica as i am using websockets.

What is best strategy and command i should use for rolling update of single instance with exposed port.

Comment: Why are you removing the service?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the order: start-first with replicas: 1.  With this setup, existing docker container is shutdown prior to startup the new docker container.  So it seem that the order start-first or stop-first doesn't really matter, or the start-first didn't work as desire.

If however I set replicas: 2, then one of the existing docker container will be replaced with a new docker container, then after that one succeeds then the second docker container is replacing the other existing docker container

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is to use `order:start-first` in the `update_config` section of the docker service in the compose file. which will start a new container before terminating the old one when you are applying rolling update or deploying a newer version.

you can check here for more details about `update_config` :https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/